# Google Maps Flutter animateCamera throws error

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps-flutter

I have successfully placed google maps on my flutter app but anytime the location update triggers I get an error on my console. The map still updates and everything works fine but I want to fully understand why I get this error and How to fix it.

Below are my full code and the error I got on the console

Error

```
E/flutter (12290): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method camera#animate on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_maps_0)
E/flutter (12290): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157:7)
E/flutter (12290): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12290): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:12)
E/flutter (12290): #2      MethodChannelGoogleMapsFlutter.animateCamera (package:google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_google_maps_flutter.dart:294:10)
E/flutter (12290): #3      GoogleMapController.animateCamera (package:google_maps_flutter/src/controller.dart:160:39)
E/flutter (12290): #4      HomeState.getLocation.<anonymous closure> (package:harpy/activities/Home.activity.dart:45:20)
E/flutter (12290): #5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter (12290): #6      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (12290): #7      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (12290): #8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)
E/flutter (12290): #9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)
E/flutter (12290): #10     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:127:11)
E/flutter (12290): #11     _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:224:10)
E/flutter (12290): #12     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:157:13)
E/flutter (12290): #13     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter (12290): #14     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (12290): #15     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (12290): #16     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)
E/flutter (12290): #17     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:611:14)
E/flutter (12290): #18     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:730:11)
E/flutter (12290): #19     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:687:7)
E/flutter (12290): #20     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
E/flutter (12290): #21     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (12290): #22     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter (12290): #23     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter (12290): #24     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter (12290): #25     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (12290): #26     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter (12290): #27     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter (12290): #28     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter (12290): #29     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
E/flutter (12290): 
Restarted application in 4,395ms.
```

Full Code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:harpy/widgets/BottomSheet.widget.dart';
import 'package:harpy/widgets/Navigation.widget.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => HomeState();

}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  BitmapDescriptor userLocationIcon;
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  Location _location = Location();
  LocationData _locationData;
  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
  Set<Marker> _markers = {};

  bool expand = false;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  getLocation() async{
    mapController = await _controller.future;

    _location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
      LatLng latLng = LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);

      _markers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId("myLocation"),
          position: latLng,
          icon: userLocationIcon,
          rotation: currentLocation.heading)
      );

      CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17.4);

     mapController.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

      setStateIfMounted(() {
        _locationData = currentLocation;
      });

    });
  }

  void setStateIfMounted(f) {
    if (mounted) setState(f);
  }

  onExpand(){
    setState(() { expand = !expand; });
  }

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    if(expand){
      setState(() { expand = false; });
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  createMarkerImages(){
    BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5), 'assets/images/car.png').then((onValue) {
      userLocationIcon = onValue;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    createMarkerImages();
    getLocation();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    mapController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          drawer: Navigation(),
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: _size.height - (_size.height / 3),
                child: GoogleMap(
                    markers: _markers,
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                    zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                    mapType: MapType.normal,
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(this._locationData?.latitude ?? 6.7008168, this._locationData?.longitude ?? -1.6998494),
                      zoom: 14.4746,
                    ),
                    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                      _controller.complete(controller);
                    }
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 20,
                left: 20,
                child: Container(
                  height: 45,
                  width: 45,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                            spreadRadius: 3,
                            blurRadius: 10,
                            offset: Offset(0, 1)
                        )
                      ]
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                    onPressed: ()=> _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              CustomBottomSheet(onPressed: onExpand, expand: expand)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a streamsubscription variable;

`StreamSubscription<LocationData> streamHandler;`

referenced it to the subscription and cancelled it in the dispose metho

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    mapController.dispose();
    streamHandler.cancel();
  }
```

and I don't see the error anymore :).

Answer (score -1):

Go to File->Invalidate Cache/Restart.

it will work then.

Comment: Thank you very much I tried a different approach and it seems to work fine for now but if it shows up again I will try your suggestion. :)

Comment: it will not show. it was causing because plugin was not loaded properly.

Comment: please accept and upvote the Answer so that other can understand which is the working answer!